# How do I get a docker image from a fileserver into my local registry?

Tags: image, docker, repository

Please pardon my simple question, I'm still a bit of a newbie with Docker.

I have a number of docker images on a file server. These were not created by me, but uploaded there by a developer.

I would like to experiment with them and have set up a docker server including registery on a local linux mint system.

I can easily download the image into my local Downloads directory, but have not been able to find out how to get it into the registery or run it in any other way.

Any hints would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Docker images don't usually live on file servers, or otherwise exist as files you can directly manipulate.  What format are these images in?  Do you know how they got there initially?

Answer (score 1):

you could accomplish that by tagging your images with the register server IP and port, then push to this registry

```
docker tag hello <registry-host>:<port>/hello
docker push <registry-host>:<port>/hello
```

Then you can pull them by using **docker pull** command 
you can check the docs for more info
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/